# Login из ad ldap при авторизации

Tags: ldap, active-directory

Как я могу сделать сквозную авторизацию по имени пользователя из ad ldap? Как идея, можно завязаться на ie и там получить имя, но хотелось бы кроссбраузерности.

Как понимаю, PHP тут бессильно. Это надо делать на ASP ?

Каким образом это можно реализовать? Т.е. пользователь заходит на внутренний портал, я получаю его логин из ад и если он есть в базе, то его пропускает

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что имеется в виду под сквозной авторизацией? Пользователь вводит пароль от своей AD учетки?

Comment: И как бы PHP тоже умеет работать с LDAP.

Comment: и как вы получите текущего пользователя?:

Comment: А как пользователь авторизовывается? Он же должен хоть что-то ввести, хотя бы логин-пароль... вот их и проверяем в LDAP. Или я не поняла вопрос... У нас так все студенты в Moodle (PHP) входят...

Comment: Или Вам нужно в веб-приложении получить данные пользователя, авторизованного в операционной системе на доменном ПК? Из Вашего вопроса это не ясно...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос: Вам необходимо получить имя текущего пользователя, авторизованного в операционной системе на доменном ПК.

Если PHP-приложение установлено на IIS, то это делается через переменную `AUTH_USER`. Проверила - работает на IE, Chrome и FireFox. Вот мой проверочный пример кода:

```
<?php   
   echo $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
?>
```

В результате получаю имя пользователя в виде: `MYDOMAIN\user.name`

Есть только одно НО! Чтобы это решение действительно заработало, Вам придется отказаться от другого типа аутентификации на сайте (т.е. только через AD).

Вот что нужно сделать в IIS: у сайта в настройках аутентификации (Authentication) включаете (Enable) "Windows Authentication" и обязательно (!) отключаете анонимный доступ (Anonymous authentication).

В IE и Chrome заработает сразу, а FireFox нужно будет сначала поставить это дополнение и прописать сайт в доверенные: https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/integrated-auth-for-firefox/

Answer (score -2):

\ldap_auth\ldap_auth\index.aspx.cs

довольно грязно впрочем

myIdentity.Name отдаст имя из ад лдап

на стороне пхп можно сделать обработку имени

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;

namespace ldap_auth
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void SimpleAuth()
        {
            WindowsIdentity myIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            string identName = myIdentity.Name;
            string URI = "http://techbase.ru/mining";
            Response.Clear();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<html>");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
            sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='get'>", URI);
            sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{0}'>", identName);
            // Other params go here
            sb.Append("</form>");
            sb.Append("</body>");
            sb.Append("</html>");
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SimpleAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть кто угодно сможет сделать POST-запрос с любым именем пользователя на указанный вами адрес - и зайти под его именем?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что открыли огромную дыру на своем сайте?

Comment: я не говорю что это идеал. но в свою учетку же юзер попал. вот и авторизация

Comment: Авторизация - это когда юзер не может попасть в чужую

Comment: а он и не может. он же не знает чужого пароля от учетки

Comment: а зачем ему знать пароль? Он сделает POST-запрос на адрес `http://techbase.ru/mining` - и войдет вообще без пароля.